# Suppress the message "Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!" in Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

Am using Selenium in Python. This is the few lines of code I am using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='question-summary narrow']")

for question in questions:
   # Do some processing here...
```

Now, while processing, I keep getting this message **"Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!"**, even though I am not using *Qt* or *Qmake* in my program (of course, I am using Windows 10 OS). Although it is only a warning message, it is annoying (at least for my supervisor). I am wondering if there is a way to get rid of this.

Comment: Please include a relevant section of your code and the complete error you are getting.  Also, outline the steps you have taken to resolve.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me and could fix it by installing the latest version of [Qt open source](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5). It would consume lots of disk space though.

Hope that helps for you as well.

Comment: any idea how to reduce size?

Comment: @JessyMol You can customize the installation to select only one version of Qt.